# Cordova: Play media not stored on SD card

Tags: android, cordova, audio, mp3, media

In my Cordova app project I have downloaded an audio file as MP3 in my Android dataDirectory at "file:///data/data/com.iappedyou.mobile/files/audio1.mp3".

When I now try to play that file through

```
function playMP3_3() {
   var mp3URL = cordova.file.dataDirectory + "audio1.mp3";
   var media = new Media(mp3URL, null, mediaError);
   media.play();
}
```

I get a "Media Error – Code: 1".

According to [Simon's blog post](http://simonmacdonald.blogspot.com/2011/05/using-media-class-in-phonegap.html) Android assumes that the file is stored on your "/sdcard". But how can I play an audio file by using dataDirectory?

Thank you